# Jump cursor to row containing specified ID without iterating through all records

Tags: android

I have a cursor with multiple records, and each record has a unique "_id" column plus other columns.

I want to know if it is possible to retrieve a particular record with a specified _id, widout iterating over all d records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, Cursor is a resultset, you can perform join operation on cursor, but can't access records by values.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your question, you could also request a new cursor for the particular record you want. 
example:

```
rawQuery("SELECT * FROM simpletable WHERE _id="+YOUR_ID_VALUE,null);
```

Comment: yeah, this is one way of doing it, although not so efficient...thnx :)